# How do i keep only two horizontal frame buffers in Emacs?

Tags: macos, emacs, ide, editor

Every time i open emacs it open with one large window buffer on top, and one smaller on the bottom, i like the way that is. The problem comes when i either compile, or pull up the shell using mx, it splits the top window vertically into two, thus leaving me with three window buffers. So my question is, how can i stop this from happening? and also, how can i make the compilation and shell go to the bottom window buffer?

I have no clue how i can edit my .emacs file for this to happen the way i want it.

Comment: It is *probably* just a matter of setting `split-width-threshold` and `split-height-threshold` to suit your needs:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17872/algorithm-on-deciding-splitting-vertically-or-horizontally